# What are some idiomatic ways to create “dependency inversion” in rust?

Tags: rust, architecture, clean-architecture

I’m looking to create “dependency inversion” in rust (as described in  Robert C. Martin‘s *Clean Architecture*).

I’ve been trying to implement this in my rust projects: Being able to write code thats dependent on the modules that **it** makes up, rather than vise-versa. (I don't need any actual **runtime** polymorphism, hence rust.)

What would be some clean ways to implement such a system? Thanks for the help.

My solution to the problem has been to use traits and trait bound generics to act as interfaces.

ie:

```
struct Car<W: WheelsTrait, S: SeatTrait>{
wheels: [W;4],
seat: S,
}
```

But this led to generics spreading and building up in higher level modules. Not to mention that trait bounds were cluttering my `impl`s.

I’ve tried some other, increasingly un-idiomatic, methods: like having a type aliases for each `struct` with the generics removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement DI with generics, then the generics will spread all throughout the codebase. Furthermore, I am not sure you will even get all the benefits of DI with generics.

What you want is runtime polymorphism. That is, dynamic dipatch.

```rust
struct Car {
  wheels: [Box<dyn Wheel>; 4],
  seat: Box<dyn Seat>,
}
```

With this, you no longer have to deal with generics spreading. But if you do this for all your types, you might as well use Java. At least that runtime is optimised for massive dynamicism.

Instead, in Rust, what you would do is that you would define domain boundaries. Components that really do make sense to switch around. Structs that make big decisions: which database to use, which output format to use, how to read input. In other words, decisions that affect how your program will interact with the rest of the world.

For other things, you will probably use DI to mock the internal parts. The solution to that is, use feature-flags, or just, don't. Test your structs end to end, switching out only the boundaries when in different environments.

Comment: I see, so it looks like a more "pure" dependency inversion is not really suited for rust. It's more for something like java. So you are suggesting having a single large struct that will have the swap ins for the various modules?

Comment: I should probably specify that my goal isn't actual polymorphism at runtime, just the ability to work with the code AS IF it were polymorphic. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Even if your goal isn't runtime polymorphism, if you want to contain your generics to a small part, you need runtime polymorphism. A single large struct is absolutely not the right way to code. Not in rust and not anywhere else. Code as you usually do and swap out some things with Box<dyn That thing> where it makes sense.